# How to delete Windows 7 File Recovery backup files?

Tags: windows-8

Windows 7 File Recovery doesn't see backups created in the past and I can't delete them from hdd because apparently 'file is open in System'.

How to delete them?

Comment: Tried in safe mode? If nothing else a Linux LiveCD/USB should help.

Comment: Is the HDD an internal HDD or external one?

Comment: Thx, save mode helped. Backup was on internal drive.